# How can I change the color of placeholder of matInput?

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to change the color matInput place holder. I am able to change the color of underline but nothing is working for placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

The Angular document mentions that the 
[placeholder ref](https://v8.material.angular.io/components/input/overview#placeholder)

> The placeholder can be specified by setting the `placeholder` attribute on the `<input>` or `<textarea>` element. In some cases that `<mat-form-field>` may use the placeholder as the label.

Accordingly you can place the css.

For `mat-form-field`

```
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
      color: red !important;
}

.mat-form-field-empty .mat-form-field-label {
    color: green;
}
```

OR in case of simple `mat-input`, play with placeholder attribute of HTML input.

```
::placeholder{
  color: pink;
}
```